# To set Textview in a Extreme Right corner and middle of the Action Bar

Tags: android, resize, actionbarsherlock

I have implemented Sherlock Actionbar,presently there is one textview which is changing dynamically.I want to set the 3 text view extreme right corner and middle and the last one in extreme left.How can i achieve this? textview gravity is not working neither the layout gravity.is their any way to implement this?My code for the text view which is displaying right now in the left most corner of the action bar.

```
    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actiontext, null);
    mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.menutesttext);

    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

and my xml file for the text view is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/expand_activities_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="true"
android:addStatesFromChildren="true">

<TextView android:id="@+id/menutesttext"
    android:layout_width="82dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Testing"/>
   </FrameLayout>
```

Now what i want is to set another 2 text views in this frame layout and make it adjustable in my actionbar like,

```
TEXTVIEW1       TEXTVIEW2       TEXTVIEW3
```

I dont want to implement Tab views.Just want to implement 3 textview in the above way.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should do with your FrameLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/expand_activities_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:addStatesFromChildren="true">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/menutesttextcenter"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Testing"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/menutesttextright"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Testing"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/menutesttextleft"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Testing"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Or, you can easily achieve this with using the LinearLayout below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCenter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this Relative layout inside the toolbar tags.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/txt_pumpname"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:paddingTop="33dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```